# Is there a way to stop the tkinter entry looping?

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, conditional-statements

I created a while for loop which should check if entry has 2, 3 or 4 in it.  When I tried the loop without the tkinter entry box it looped and stopped as required.  When I incorporated it with the tkinter entry it loops endlessly.  I am quite new to python tkinter and trying to get a working system.

Already tried the loop without the tkinter Entry.  Have researched for quite some hours now.

```
from tkinter import *
def sentence():
    global text 
    text = musicEntry.get()
    musicEntry.delete(0,END)
    countIt = 0
    while countIt == 0:             
        for line in text:
            if line in "2" or line in "3" or line in "4":
                countIt = 1
                messagebox.showinfo("All is well. Please press the SUBMIT button to continue")
                break
        else:
            print("This doesn't work")

def checkPass():
    global musicEntry
    enterText = Tk()
    enterText.title ("Welcome to music chooser")
    Label(enterText, text = "Please enter the music text", bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=7, column = 0, sticky=W) 

    #Create a text entry box for music level
    musicEntry = Entry(enterText, width=75, bg="white")
    musicEntry.grid(row=8, column=0, sticky=W)
    validateButton = Button(enterText, text="Validate", width=6, command=sentence) .grid(row=9, column=0, sticky=W)
checkPass()
```

I expect the validation to catch the missing 2, 3 or 4 when the else executes so that I can then have a messagebox for the user.

Comment: `line in "2"` is true for exactly two possible values of `line`: `""` and `"2"`.  The only conceivable value that would simultaneously be `in "2"`, `in "3"`, and `in "4"` is the empty string.  You probably want to use `"2" in line` instead.

Comment: Throw away your *looping*, do `if text and text in '234':`

Comment: I've tried both ways.  Changing the 2 in line and 3 in line and 4 in line gives the same result - continuous output of "This doesn't work". I then tried the if text and text in '234' and that gives the continuous output for correct and incorrect entry.

Comment: I've solved it.  I was not terminating the loop in the else statement.